# Creating single use intermediate variables

Tags: variables, coding-style

I've read somewhere that a variable should be entered into the code if it is reused. But when I write my code for logic transparency, I sometimes create intermediate variables (with names reflecting what they contain) which are used only once.
How incorrect is this concept? 
PS:
I want to do it right.

Comment: Some would say that you should avoid even using such intermediate variables at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note that most of the time clarity takes precedence over re-usability or brevity. This is one of the basic principles of clean code. Most modern compilers optimize code anyway so creating new variables need not be a concern at all.

It is perfectly fine to create a new variable if it would add clarity to your code. Make sure to give it a meaningful name. Consider the following function:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(final int yyyy) {
    if ((yyyy % 4) != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else if ((yyyy % 400) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((yyyy % 100) == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Even though the boolean expressions are used only once, they may confuse the reader of the code. We can rewrite it as follows

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    boolean fourth = year % 4 == 0;
    boolean hundredth = year % 100 == 0;
    boolean fourHundredth = year % 400 == 0;
    return fourth && (!hundredth || fourHundredth);
}
```

These boolean variables add much more clarity to the code.

This example is from the Clean Code book by Robert C. Martin.